# Thymeleaf template doesn't work insde SpringBoot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin, thymeleaf

I have the following controller
https://github.com/iva-nova-e-katerina/mysite_v2/blob/main/src/main/kotlin/net/iceja/controller/FrontPageController.java
But "index" template doesn't work.
localhost:8080

```
Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
Sun May 14 14:58:08 MSK 2023
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available
```

you can clone my project to see

```
git clone git@github.com:iva-nova-e-katerina/mysite_v2.git
```

Or browse it in github, please tell me what am I doing wrong

Comment: sorry, your repo "works" (doesn't reproduce the issue)... (`mvn clean spring-boot:run`)

Comment: It is better to add the relevant information directly into the question, instead of only relying on links to external locations.

Comment: ..it "works", but controller is not compiled! (java files in src/main/kotlin, really !?)

Comment: @xerx593 you are correct, cleaning cache helps!! This project is mixed one - Java + Kotlin